# How to run anaconda?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I just started using python, and I want to have some fun with TensorFlow. But I have stuck in the installation of Anaconda. When I installed it this is the error what I'm getting:

[image: When I installed it this is the error what I'm getting]

What should I do? How should I add TensorFlow to my project. I'm an absolute beginner.

[These ate my variables, sorry for the Hungarian language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMxXH.png)

Comment: What is Anaconda folder? Does it contain non-ascii characters?

Comment: Yes, I tried to reinstall it several times.

Comment: Also you may try update/install `qt` with anaconda console command.

Comment: I downloaded 64-bit graphic installer  from https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this issue :

1. Access the Environmental Variables dialog:

   a. Right-click the Windows Start button and then select System.
   b. Click the 'Advanced system settings' link.
   c. Click Environment Variables.
2. Under user and system variables, look for the QT_PLUGIN_PATH variable. If this variable exists, take note of the current value in case you need to reverse the change. Then select the variable and click 'Delete'.
3. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
4. Reinstall Anaconda

Comment: I checked I don't have qt

Comment: Not, unfortunately :(